# PHP - detect whitespace between strings

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

How would I go about detecting whitespace between strings? For example, I have a name string like:

"Jane Doe"

Keep in mind that I don't want to trim or replace it, just detect if whitespace exists between the first and second string.

Comment: hi i just want to ask, is ctype_space ( string $text ) in the phpmanual http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php will not work to detect the whitespace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP check if string contains space between words (not at beginning or end)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142882/php-check-if-string-contains-space-between-words-not-at-beginning-or-end)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use preg_match as suggested by Josh:

```
<?php

$foo = 'Bob Williams';
$bar = 'SamSpade';
$baz = "Bob\t\t\tWilliams";

var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$foo));
var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$bar));
var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$baz));
```

Ouputs:

```
int(1)
int(0)
int(1)
```

Comment: i guess i've always considered whitespace the space as space unless your using html entities.

Comment: if we talk about web, use the KISS method please, you don't want to start the regex engine just to justify lazyness

Answer (score 8):

You could check for only alphanumerical characters, which whitespace is not. You could also do a strpos for a space.

```
if(strpos($string, " ") !== false)
{
   // error
}
```

Comment: You want it like strpos($string, " ") instead. Haystack first, then needle

Comment: As stated by Josh, this is not a valid answer to the OP question. The OP wanted to detect "whitespace" not "spaces".

Comment: The author's name is even "lacking preg_match". LOL.

Comment: sorry guys. i meant spaces. thought whitespace was equal to space.

Comment: Why couldn't they standardize how needle/haystack functions take arguments. Should always have one first.

Comment: @Terw I fixed it in my answer

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't [preg_match("/\s/",$string)](http://www.php.net/preg_match) work? The advantage to this over strpos is that it will detect any whitespace, not just spaces.

Comment: I have a fear that if I call on my regex engine for something like finding a single character it will get mad at me and start outputting profanity :(

Comment: Maybe you don't feed it enough! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You may use something like this:

```
if (strpos($r, ' ') > 0) {
    echo 'A white space exists between the string';
}
else
{
    echo 'There is no white space in the string';
}
```

This will detect a space, but not any other kind of whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

http://no.php.net/strpos

```
<?php
if(strpos('Jane Doe', ' ') > 0)
    echo 'Including space';
else
    echo 'Without space';
?>
```

Comment: This won't work if the first character is a space - " > 0" should be " !== false"

Comment: I know, did it like that because it looked like he wanted to see if it was multiple names, not " Name" ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
// returns no. of matches if $str has nothing but alphabets,digits and spaces.
function is_alnumspace($str){
  return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i',$str);
}
```

Comment: `[a-z]` does not cover alphabetic characters.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the asker's requirements.