# How do I use preg_match to test for spaces?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How would I use the PHP function preg_match() to test a string to see if any spaces exist?

#### Example

> "this sentence would be tested true for spaces"
>
> "thisOneWouldTestFalse"

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you're interested in any white space (including tabs etc), use `\s`

```
if (preg_match("/\\s/", $myString)) {
   // there are spaces
}
```

if you're just interested in spaces then you don't even need a regex:

```
if (strpos($myString, " ") !== false)
```

Comment: You've got the strpos parameters around the wrong way. Should be:

    if (strpos($myString, " ") !== false)

Comment: @ncatnow, thanks for the heads up. That's been sitting there, wrong, for almost a year. :p

Comment: do you know where a link to a document that explains the \s \b \\S etc ?

Comment: @nickf: could you please tell me why can't we use preg_match("/\s/", $myString) instead of the "/\\s/". What different will it make?

Comment: @joHN Because inside of double quotes \ is used to escape special characters (like `\n` for a newline as an example). So you have to escape the slash (by adding the second \) so that PHP treats it as a literal slash. Honestly, a better approach is to simply encase strings with single quotes unless you need the additional functionality you get from double quotes. So in short, you can use `/\s/` as long as you encase it in single quotes like `preg_match('/\s/', $myString)`

Answer (score 4):

Also see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161708/php-detect-whitespace-between-strings) that addresses this.

And, depending on if you want to detect tabs and other types of white space, you may want to look at the perl regular expression syntax for things such as \b \w and [:SPACE:]

Comment: `\b` probably wouldn't help, since it will match the start and end of the string: eg `preg_match("/\\b/", "abc")` == true

Comment: Good point, I was just thinking "word boundaries" and not remembering it would match on the ends.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
preg_match('/[\s]+/',.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[\\S]
```

upper case- 'S' will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

How about using ctype_graph for this purpose? This would expand the scope of space to mean any "white space char" that does not print anything visible on screen (like \t, \n ) also.
However this is native and should be quicker than preg_match.

```
$x = "string\twith\tspaces" ;
if(ctype_graph($x))
    echo "\n string has no white spaces" ;
else
    echo "\n string has spaces" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

faster to use:

`strstr($string, ' ');`

Answer (score 0):

We can also check for spaces using this expression:

```
/\p{Zs}/
```

#### Test

```
function checkSpace($str)
{
    if (preg_match('/\p{Zs}/s', $str)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump((checkSpace('thisOneWouldTestFalse')));
var_dump(checkSpace('this sentence would be tested true for spaces'));
```

#### Output

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dZQojy/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/dZQojy/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.