# I have a pattern where i want to allow alphanumeric and also space especially SPACE

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I already tried many things like \n and [[:space:]] but i don't know where i should place it.

here is a bit of the code:

```
 $sPattern = '/^([-_@a-zA-Z0-9])+$/';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use preg\_match to test for spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384965/how-to-use-preg-match-to-test-for-spaces)

Comment: Do you mean `$sPattern = '/^([-_@a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]])+$/';`? But you can also use `$sPattern = '/^([-_@a-zA-Z0-9\s])+$/';`. Why did you have trouble? What was the string and what was the output?

Comment: Just add a space in the character class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still wonder what the problem was but let me explain a bit: the *POSIX character classes* (like `[:space:]`) can be only used inside regular common *character classes* (like `[a-z]`). When you use them individually, they look like `[[:space:]]+`. But when you use them with other ranges, they look like `[a-z[:space:]]`.

Now, you do not need the `[:space:]` as in PHP PCRE regex flavor, you can use a *shorthand character class* `\s`.

Also, `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (*unless* you add the `/u` modifier), so you can further shorten your pattern:

```
$sPattern = '/^[-@\w\s]+$/';
```

Also, the `+` must be put next to the closing square bracket to reduce overhead for the regex engine capturing feature. The `(...)` are redundant as you can access the whole match using Group 0 value.

**NOTE**: `[:space:]` != `\s` in PHP ([see reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)).

> The `space` characters are `HT` (9), `LF` (10), `VT` (11), `FF` (12), `CR` (13), and   (32). Notice that this list includes the `VT` character (code 11). This makes `[:space]:` different to `\s`, which does not include `VT` (for Perl compatibility).

**If you need to match `VT`, use `$sPattern = '/^[-@\w[:space:]]+$/';`**.

Comment: Please check my update, I think it is relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently a problem with the computer so i used something else :

```
    $sPattern = "/^([-_@\\w\\f])+$/";

    $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
```