# preg_replace to identify a year and add wiki codes to link it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Q. Can anyone help with the regex to correctly identify 4 digit numbers with spaces each side?

I have a wiki for documenting history, timelines. The idea is to identify years, 4 digit numbers with spaces each side then add wiki code [[ & ]] each side so the year is automatically turned into a link to its page namesake. (Excluding pages which are then year pages, no need to link to itself). I have a semi working answer but noticed it auto linked a number between a `.` and `,`.

My current php is; ($this->GetPageTag() = wiki page name)

```
// Autolink years - 
if (ctype_digit($this->GetPageTag()) && strlen($this->GetPageTag()) == '4') 
{
  // This is a year page and should not have the numbers auto linked.
} else {
  // This is anything BUT a year page so we can auto link any years. 
  $body = preg_replace('!(\b\d{4}\b)!', '[[$1]]', $body);
  // Fix problem of double bracketing, bit of a hack for the above really.
  $body = str_replace("[[[[","[[",$body);
  $body = str_replace("]]]]","]]",$body);
}
// end autolink years.
```

So the offending code in question is; 
    $body = preg_replace('!(\b\d{4}\b)!', '[[$1]]', $body);

Thanks

Comment: Use `preg_replace('~(?<!\S)\d{4}(?!\S)~', '[[$0]]', $body)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a semi working answer but noticed it auto linked a number between a `.` and `,`.

[Word boundaries `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) match at the following locations:

> > Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> >     After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> >     Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

That means, `\b\d{4}\b` matches `1990` in the `,1990.` string.

To make sure you match a string in between whitespaces or start/end of string, use

```
$body = preg_replace('~(?<!\S)\d{4}(?!\S)~', '[[$0]]', $body);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p3b1WO/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - no non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `\d{4}`  - 4 digits
- `(?!\S)` - no non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location is allowed.

In the replacement string, `$0` replacement backreference is used to insert the whole match value (no need to capture all the regex pattern).

And there is no need to remove 4 `[`s and `]`s in this case, unless you have them in the original text.

Comment: Great thanks! Thats the badger! I have added the url of this in my code comments as I am sure I will refer back to this. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the word boundaries with space in lookaround:

```
 $body = preg_replace('!(?<= )(\d{4})(?= )!', '[[$1]]', $body);
```

If you want to match also tabulations:

```
 $body = preg_replace('!(?<=\h)(\d{4})(?=\h)!', '[[$1]]', $body);
```

Comment: hmm they are not picking up any 4 digit numbers? However..     $body = preg_replace('!(\s\b\d{4}\b\s)!', '[[$1]]', $body); this removed one of the spaces but seamed to work.

Comment: @chrisdavies: Sorry, I don't get you. Please, edit your question and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: Nothing matched to add the square brackets.

Comment: @chrisdavies: There was a typo in the regex, see my edit.

Comment: ahh...  the space wasnt picked up but searching for detecting spaces I came up with this which seams to work. Here is a bit of collaboration! Cheers!     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384965/how-to-use-preg-match-to-test-for-spaces       ## pre
    2005
     2005
    .2006.
    kljlj2333lkkj
    [[LatLon:63.5623,-3.3829]]

    `$body = preg_replace('!(?<=\s)(\d{4})(?=\s)!', '[[$1]]', $body);`

    ## post - got expected result
    [[2005]]
     [[2005]]
    .2006.
    kljlj2333lkkj
    [[LatLon:63.5623,-3.3829]]

Comment: (why are all my newlines removed?)

Comment: @chrisdavies: `\s` stands for white spaces AND line break, `\h` stands for Horizontal spaces (space or tabulation).