# How to add to preg_match a space in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I use preg_match in php, and I want, that preg_match accept space, but this code not accept. I don't know where is a error.

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z-0-9_\-]{1,400}$/', $val)
```

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z-0-9_\-\s]{1,400}$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can test in any white spaces, tabs, etc with `\s`.

```
preg_match("/\\s/", $myString)
```

I guess this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1384971/5873079) can help you.