# checking space between text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check the gap between two or more words, i have given as an input, in a text box. If there had any space, then i want to alert user that no space is allowing. I can check the existence of text simply using "if else" statement. But can't do the desired stuff in this way. My code is given below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkForm()

    {

        var cName=document.getElementById("cName").value;
        var cEmail=document.getElementById("cEmail").value;

        if(cName.length<1)

        {
            alert("Please enter both informations");
            return false;
        }

        if(cEmail.length<1)
        {
            alert("Please enter your email");
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

```
        Name : <input type="text" id="cName" name="cName"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Email : <input type="text" id="cEmail" name="cEmail"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Go!"/>

        </form>
```

- Thankyou

Comment: please check this link , it will be help you
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161708/php-detect-whitespace-between-strings

Comment: You need to be clearer. State exactly what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to match all spaces between words? Do you want to ensure that words only have 1 space between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method of strings. For example:

```
'Spaces here'.match(' ');
```

That returns true.

```
'Nospace'.match(' ');
```

That returns false.

So for what you want, just use something like this:

```
if(cName.match(' ')){
   alert('Spaces found!');
   return false;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TSwvZ/)

Comment: This is simple and working. A lot of Thanks dear Amaan for giving suggestion. :):):)

Answer (score 1):

your question not very clear , but i hope you want to count your words you can use the following code to split a text and by using the length property you count the word

```
var b = document.getElementById("cName").value;
var temp = new Array();
    temp = b.split(' ');
var count= temp.length;
```

and if you want to validate your name field that should not use any space

```
if ( ^[A-Za-z]$.test(document.getElementById("cName").value) ) {
    // your code;
}

if ( document.getElementById("cName").value.indexOf(' ') > 0 ) {
    alert('space found');
}
```

Comment: yes, 2nd one is that, which i trying to do. But using this code dream waver showing a syntax error. i think the "d" of document is missing here in your code. After correction it still show the error. thnx for your replying rashmi