# PHP - make sure string has no whitespace

Tags: php

How can I check if a PHP string contains any white space?  I want to check if white space is in there, and then echo back an error message if true

```
if(strlen($username) == whitespace ){

                echo "<center>Your username must not contain any whitespace</center>";
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times but I can't find an appropriate duplicate.  you want `if (preg_match("/\s/", $username))`

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161708/php-detect-whitespace-between-strings)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
if ( preg_match('/\s/',$username) ) ....
```

Comment: still works good ;) example..  if ( preg_match('/\s/',$username) ) { echo "yep contained whitespace"; }

Comment: why its not working for me ? `if(preg_match('/\s/',$req->note){ }` for this ?

Comment: @HamelRaj you've missed a closing bracket =)

Answer (score 3):

This solution is for the **inverse problem**: to know if a string contains at least one word.

```
/**
 * Check if a string contains at least one word.
 *
 * @param string $input_string
 * @return boolean
 *  true if there is at least one word, false otherwise.
 */    
function contains_at_least_one_word($input_string) {
  foreach (explode(' ', $input_string) as $word) {
    if (!empty($word)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If the function return false there are no words in the $input_string.
So, you can do something like that:

```
if (!contains_at_least_one_word($my_string)) {
  echo $my_string . " doesn't contain any words.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
if(strlen(trim($username)) == strlen($username)) {
  // some white spaces are there.
}
```

Comment: Surely this won't check for whitespace that is *inside* `$username`? For example, `trim(" stack overflow user ")` produces `"stack overflow user"`, which clearly still has whitespace in it.

Comment: Not exactly, I guess... It'll only trim the whitespaces on both sides. Maybe a http://php.net/strpos test?

Comment: This will only test if there is whitespace on the beginning and end of $username.

Comment: it would detect whitespace ONLY on the beginning and end of $username

Answer (score 2):

Try this too :

```
if (count(explode(' ', $username)) > 1) {
  // some white spaces are there.
}
```

Comment: What if it has tabs ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ( preg_match('/\s/',$string) ){
    echo "yes $string contain whitespace";  
} else {
    echo "$string clear no whitespace ";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other Method :

```
$string = "This string have whitespace";
if( $string !== str_replace(' ','',$string) ){
    //Have whitespace
}else{
     //dont have whitespace
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found another good function which is working fine for searching some charsets in a string - [strpbrk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php)

```
if (strpbrk($string, ' ') !== false) {
    echo "Contain space";
} else {
    echo "Doesn't contain space";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides a [built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php) `ctype_space( string $text )` to check for whitespace characters. However, `ctype_space()` checks if **every** character of the string creates a whitespace. In your case, you could make a function similar to the following to check if a string has whitespace characters.

```
/**
 * Checks string for whitespace characters.
 *
 * @param string $text
 *   The string to test.
 * @return bool
 *   TRUE if any character creates some sort of whitespace; otherwise, FALSE.
 */
function hasWhitespace( $text )
{
    for ( $idx = 0; $idx < strlen( $text ); $idx += 1 )
        if ( ctype_space( $text[ $idx ] ) )
            return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}
```