# php regular expression for white space

Tags: php, regex

i would like to validate user inputs like this:
"Ahmedabad Intl-Ahmedabad,  India(AMD)", The first letter is capital and there can be space and - in the first part. and then one comma with one space, and then some letters with '(' letters ')'.
I have tried it like this:

```
preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z- ]+), ([a-zA-Z]+)([A-Z()]+)/', $string),
```

Does anyone know why it does not work? thanks

Comment: Define "does not work" http://regex101.com/r/iZ7yX6

Comment: Your statement returns `int(1)` for `$string = 'Ahmedabad Intl-Ahmedabad, India(AMD)';` and putting a `;` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add backslash to the parenthesis. Try this:

```
$string = "Ahmedabad Intl-Ahmedabad, India(AMD)";
echo  preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z- ]+, [a-zA-Z]+\([A-Z]+\)/', $string); //1

$string = "Ahmedabad Intl-Ahmedabad, India(AMD";
echo  preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z- ]+, [a-zA-Z]+\([A-Z]+\)/', $string); //0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$foo = "Dave Smith";
$bar = "SamSpade";
$baz = "Dave\t\t\tSmith";

var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$foo));
var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$bar));
var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$baz));
```

Output

```
int(1)
int(0)
int(1)
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161708/php-detect-whitespace-between-strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (preg_match('~^[A-Z][a-z]*+(?>[ -][A-Z][a-z]*)*+, [A-Z][a-z]*\([A-Z]+\)$~', $string)) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```