# Code needed for validation of a text field "without" whitespaces included in PHP

Tags: php

This is the code for validation of a text field "with" whitespaces allowed :-

```
function validateFirstName($fname){

if(empty($fname)){
    $firstnameErr = "First name is required";
    return $firstnameErr;
} else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fname)){ // check if name only contains letters and whitespace.Performs a regular expression match
    $firstnameErr = "Only letters are allowed";
    return $firstnameErr;
} 
   return ''; 
}
```

I wanted the other part of the else if code of the same function which throws an error if there are whitespaces

Comment: preg_match("/\\s/", $fname) will return true if white space found

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161708/php-detect-whitespace-between-strings) out :)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn’t a website to get professional programmers to write code for you for free.

Answer (score 0):

// using  Jquery

```
  else if($.trim($fname).length==0){
        $firstnameErr = "Value required";     
   }
```

// pure javascript without jquery

```
  else if($fname.replace(/\s+/g,'').length ==0){
        $firstnameErr = "Value required";     
   }
```

// in php

```
  else if(strlen(trim($fname))==0){
        $firstnameErr = "Value required";     
   }
```

Comment: Javascript isn't a tag, only PHP is, however, a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
 return $fname.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
```

Or you can use the test method, on a simple RegEx:

```
 return /\s/g.test($fname);
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends by what you are interested in:

if you're searching for whitespace only, you could use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/it/function.strpos.php) function:

```
if (strpos($fname, " ") !== false) // whitespaces were found!
```

if you need to check every whitespace char (so tabs included, and more than one whitespace) you have to use the regexp specifying `\s` that will search for whitespaces:

```
if (preg_match("/\\s/", $fname)) // okay, there are whitespaces in string (tabs, double spaces, etc...)!
```

in these cases, when the condition is true, you can launch an exception.