# ctype_space does not work with $_GET values

Tags: php

I call URL:

```
http://www.example.com/?check=aaa bbb ccc
```

and the following lines check if $_GET values contain whitespaces:

```
if (isset($_GET)) {
  while(list($name,$value) = each($_GET)) { 

    if (ctype_space($value)) {
      echo "contains spaces";
    } else {
      echo "no spaces<br />";
    }

    echo $value;
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
no spaces
aaa bbb ccc
```

My question is: `why ctype_space` function can not find whitespaces in the string "`aaa bbb ccc`"?

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php function `ctype_space` return tru if all character are a whitespace character

Comment: Because you are using the function wrong? [See ctype_space](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php) - Perhaps you could checkout this question + answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161708/php-detect-whitespace-between-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because function checks if variable == whitespaces

you can replace it with this function:

```
if (preg_match("/(\r|\n|\t|\s)/", $value)){
```

Comment: There is a tip on the preg_match page that reads: `Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() instead as it will be faster. `

Comment: it will be faster if you will use in while(1) for long time, we all have quad core cpus no need to use strpos as raw, it is used inside preg_match

Comment: It will most certainly NOT be faster under ANY circumstances. Please do not give out false information, it is very simple to test. Also your regex is matching tabs and linebreaks which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: belive me i have server with 1000 requests per second with lot of preg_match, no problem at all, script execution time is not longer than 0.05ms with all mysql requests.

Comment: It is your right to write poor code, but I'm fairly sure the people who wrote PHP know better than you.

Answer (score 2):

the function ctype_space, Returns TRUE if every character in text creates some sort of white space

For example,

"\n\r\t" return true
"\nABC " return false

More information in 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php

Try

```
$subject = "aaa bbb ccc"; $pattern = " ";

if ( strpos($subject, $pattern) !== false ) {
      echo "contains spaces"; } else {
      echo "no spaces<br />"; }
```

Comment: strpos will never return true. It may return a number that equates to true (== true), but not if the first character is a space. You need to check for `!== false` (or `=== false`)

Answer (score 1):

`ctype_space` only checks if ALL characters in the string are whitespaces. If you want to check if the string just contains a space, you should use another method, for example [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
   echo "contains spaces";
}
```