# PHP check if string contains space between words (not at beginning or end)

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I need to check if a string contains a space between words, but not at beginning or end. Let's say there are these strings:

```
1: "how r u ";
2: "how r u";
3: " howru";
```

Then only `2` should be true.  How could I do that?

Comment: compare the original string with the trimmed string, and if they're the same length then true

Comment: Ok good idea ^^ thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm afraid, you've misunderstood the question

Comment: @heximal not really, you can just check if last and first character is a space and if not then check for space in whole string

Comment: @chris85 yes it will, ok maybe i should have say "anywhere in string but not at begin or end"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can verify that the trimmed string is equal to the original string and then use `strpos` or `str_contains` to find a space.

```
// PHP < 8
if ($str == trim($str) && strpos($str, ' ') !== false) {
    echo 'has spaces, but not at beginning or end';
}

// PHP 8+
if ($str == trim($str) && str_contains($str, ' ')) {
    echo 'has spaces, but not at beginning or end';
}
```

---

**Some more info if you're interested**

If you use `strpos()`, in this case, you don't *have to* use the strict comparison to `false` that's usually necessary when checking for a substring that way. That comparison is usually needed because if the string *starts with* the substring, `strpos()` will return `0`, which evaluates as `false`.

Here it is impossible for `strpos()` to return `0`, because the initial comparison
`$str == trim($str)` eliminates the possibility that the string starts with a space, so you can also use this if you like:

```
if ($str == trim($str) && strpos($str, ' ')) { ...
```

---

If you want to use a regular expression, you can use this to check specifically for space characters:

```
if (preg_match('/^[^ ].* .*[^ ]$/', $str) { ...
```

Or this to check for any whitespace characters:

```
if (preg_match('/^\S.*\s.*\S$/', $str) { ...
```

I did some simple testing (just timing repeated execution of this code fragment) and the trim/strpos solution was about twice as fast as the preg_match solution, but I'm no regex master, so it's certainly possible that the expression could be optimized to improve the performance.

Comment: strpos(trim($str), ' ') !== false must be

Comment: @heximal That would result in 1 from example above be true (and my answer to the caption), but if only 2 should be true the answer is right.

Comment: yes, you're right) by default the rest of expressions are not calculated if the previous fails.

Answer (score 4):

If your string is at least two character long, you could use:

```php
if (preg_match('/^\S.*\S$/', $str)) {
    echo "begins and ends with character other than space";
} else {
    echo "begins or ends with space";
}
```

Where `\S` stands for any character that is not a space.

Answer (score 0):

you can acces letter in a array

```
for($i = 1 ; i < strlen($word)-1 ; $i++ )
{
 if($word[$i] = " " ;
 {
  echo "space" ;
 }
}
```

Comment: a cycle does not give the performance, what does it happened if `$word` is too long ?